# How to check if an object is nil in a view in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to display a line of text only if an object called @foo is set.
In my view, I'm trying something like this:

```
<% if !@foo.new_record? || !@foo.nil? %>
    Foo is not a new record or nil
<% end %>
```

But this fails, returning `You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!`
I'm pretty sure this happens because of the `new_record?` method.
How do I check if something is not a new record or nil without causing an error?
In PHP, it would be achieved by asking `if(!empty($foo))` but even the `empty?` method in rails causes the same error to be returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
<% if !@foo.nil? && !@foo.new_record? %>
  Hello!
<% end %>
```

First off, you need to be using AND logic rather than OR logic here, since *any* ActiveRecord object meets at least one the requirements of "not nil" or "not a new record".

Second, checking for nil first ensures that the second check isn't run if the first one fails. The error is thrown because you can't use `#new_record?` on an object that doesn't support it, so checking for nil first ensures that that method is never run on a nil.

Comment: You could also pretty it up slightly with DeMorgan's Law: `unless @foo.nil? || @foo.new_record?; puts 'Hello!'; end;`

Comment: `!foo.nil?` makes my brain bleed because it can simply be replaced by `foo`.  Making this a very simple and common ruby idiom: `if @foo && !@foo.new_record?`

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in these as well:

```
<%= @foo.text if @foo.present? %>
```

or

```
<%= @foo.text unless @foo.blank? %>
```

Comment: these don't check if @foo is empty, but thanks for the extra methods

Answer (score 3):

Let me throw another answer just for fun.

```
unless @foo.nil? or @foo.new_record?
  "Hello"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check by `if @foo && @foo.id`.  This checks that there is a @foo activerecord object and makes sure the `id` field is not empty.  If the `id` field is empty, that means it's not a record in the database yet.  I assume you are using `id` field in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is

```
<% if !@foo.try(:new_record) %>
  Hello!
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why this object might be nil when it gets to the view? Sometimes adding conditional logic like this in the view can be a sign that something could be refactored and you are just masking a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer to use the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) for these checks.

```
if @foo.andand.id
  "Hello!"
end
```

The call to .id will only be made on non-nil objects.