# Check for nil Nil:Class in liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

How to check for nil Nil:class in abc.liquid  template . for eg:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {%  if cart.name.nil? %}
    <div>
      N.A.
   </div>
  {% endif %}
  <tr>
    <td align="left" id="product_name_{{ item.id }}"><a href="{{ item.product.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="2" value="{{ item.quantity }}" name="item_quantity_{{ item.id }}" id="item_quantity_{{ item.id }}" /></td>
    <td align="right">{{ item.unit_price | money : store }}</td>
    <td align="right">{{ item.price | money : store }}</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="item_check_{{ item.id }}" id="item_check_{{ item.id }}"></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Where in this code do you want to check for nil? You're already doing it in the second line there.

Comment: This code is under the liquid template handler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an object is nil in a view in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346234/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nil-in-a-view-in-ruby)